# cassandra queries with order by

Tags: cassandra, sql-order-by

I have a table in cassandra and I need only these 2 queries :

```
SELECT * FROM comment WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY date_posted DESC;
SELECT date_posted FROM comment WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY date_posted DESC LIMIT 1;
```

My table is :

```
CREATE TABLE comment
(
    id text,
    post_id text,
    username text,
    comment text,
    date_posted timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id), date_posted)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date_posted DESC);
CREATE INDEX comment_post_id ON comment (post_id);
```

I don't understand why it's not working, the order by is not working

Answer (score 2):

you can’t do No arbitrary ORDER BY clauses in CQL.
The CQL WHERE clause only works 
for indexed columns, specifically columns in the primary key (both the partition key and the clustering 
columns), and columns that have secondary indexes on them.
In case of secondary indexes query took data from multiple partitions,
so it will not come as a sorted order.
That is the reason Cassandra not allowing OrderBy in the above case.

You can refer this link for further details

[Breaking Down the CQL Where Clause](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/flite-breaking-down-the-cql-where-clause/)

Comment: I understand that I can't use arbitrary ORDER BY but I want to only make these 2 queries with my table and I don't understand what's wrong with my table definition

Comment: you can use your post_id as partition key.Then it will solve the issue.

Comment: you cannot use orderby with secondary index. That's wrong with your table definition for that two queries .

Answer (score 0):

You are querying based on secondary index and order by clause is not supported along with secondary index.
And if those are the only 2 queries you will be doing on comment table then `post_id` as partition key will be much more efficient.